# How do I improve my GCP datastore query performance?

Tags: database, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, latency

I have data in Google datastore. The thing I'm developing makes two http requests to my node.js backend. They both take longer than I'd like. I'm only focusing on trying to improve the response time for one of them (the heaviest request). I modified the node.js code on the backend to time the duration of the GCP datastore query. I've compiled data for 40 calls to the database. I can compile more if you'd like. I put all of the data into an excel spreadsheet, but I've also created images of the information held within, to include in this stackoverflow post. It is included further below.

The size of the payload from the database is only: `1.5 KB` according to chrome debugger.

The datastore calls were made once every 3 minutes.

Here is the function that makes the datastore call:

```
async function listReviews(brand, sku, res) {

  const kind = 'ScoredReviewFragment'

  const query = datastore.createQuery(brand, kind)

  if (brand != 'demo')
    query.filter('sku', sku)

  const [reviews] = await datastore.runQuery(query)

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.json(reviews)
}
```

Personally, I'd love to have the highest total time taken for the datastore call to be sub 100ms. As far as an average database call time, I'd love for that to be 50ms or lower. Is this possible with Google datastore? Am I hoping for too much?

Inside of google chrome debugger, I have looked at these two queries. >98%, or almost 90%, depending on how you measure it, of the time spent from the perspective of the browser is waiting for a response of the server. The download time is almost nothing. Please see included hover-tooltip for the chrome debugger information on the particular database call in question.

[image: Chrome debugger tooltip for GCP Datastore call]

The data I compiled in the excel spreadsheet shows the following:

[image: excel spreadsheet data]

If more information is needed to debug this problem please let me know and I'd be happy to provide it. Help me understand: How do I improve the GCP datastore query response time? Or is there a better way to properly debug the datastore queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the best practices listed here as a quick reference as keys-only [1](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#keys) query is a potentially fastest way to access query results and reduce the latency. However, there are some other good options that you can apply to your system based on your needs. You can still use ‘projection query’[2](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries) or replace your offsets to ‘cursor’[3](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#cursors_limits_and_offsets), you can find more detailed kind of queries in the following documentation[4](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#queries).

Other best practices[5](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices) that should help you to improve the efficiency of your application such as use batch operation performing multiple Cloud Datastore call[6](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use correct region for your database location. To locate the latency correctly you need to trace the request and measure latency inside your server.

Also if this is mission critical there are other DBs that provide better latency like MemoryStore and BigTable. These are different products with different nature.